# 0:1 Relationship in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

Is it possible to create a 0:1 Relationship in MS Dynamics CRM 2016 with using standard relationship (1:N) and workflow (without plugin or javascript) ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a cardinality of 0..1 I can think of is a Many to One relationship (N:1), where the referenced entity can be null (0) or not (1).

Example: an account has a relationship to the parent account, which is also an account. This is a N:1 relationship where you could have accounts with Parent accounts (1) or accounts without a parent (0).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How to ensure that the entity is linked to only one entity and not to N ?

Comment: No prob. There's no out of the box solution for that. One option would be a custom plugin which fires on the Associate message.

Comment: It is possible, but more messy. Workflows will run asynchronously, therefore after the association, so you'll have to delete the association somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The way I try to look at 1:1 relationships (and by proxy 0:1) is with Sections on the form. So you add a section on the form with the fields associated with that relationship and a pertinent Section name.  If the fields are populated you have a 1:1.  If they are not it's a 0:1 relationship.  This is would be a no-code, no-workflow, approach to your problem.

If you want to get fancy with it you could also establish business rules to dynamically handle the events associated with the population of said fields.